# pow or ** for very large number in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numpy

I am trying to calculate some `num1**num2` in Python. But the problem is that `num1` is `93192289535368032L` and `num2` is `84585482668812077L`, which are very large numbers.

I tried several methods as follows: First, I tried to calculate it by using the `**` operator. But it took too much time (I waited about 2 hours, but I got no result).

Second, I used `math.pow(num1, num2)`. But I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    math.pow(84585482668812077L, 93192289535368032L)
OverflowError: math range error
```

Finally, I used `numpy.power`:

```
numpy.power(84585482668812077, 93192289535368032)
-9223372036854775808
```

As you see, it gave me minus.

What I really want to do is `result = (num1**num2)` and then the `result % num3`. So, I need to calculate this power value efficiently.

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you're doing `(num1 ** num2) % num3`, you should look into the generalization of `Fermat's Litte Theorem`. Look it up on wikipedia

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks for good reference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should pass num3 as the 3rd parameter to `pow`

```
pow(...)
    pow(x, y[, z]) -> number

    With two arguments, equivalent to x**y.  With three arguments,
    equivalent to (x**y) % z, but may be more efficient (e.g. for longs).
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to import "math" for using pow. But there is default pow in Python itself.

Comment: You don't want to import `pow` from `math`-- that's the C `pow`, which doesn't accept the third argument.

Comment: @confused_at_times, `math.pow` does the calculation in floating point. The loss of precision is unacceptable here even if result fits in the floating point range. Also it's really not practical to just do the mod at the end when large numbers are involved.

Comment: Sorry, comment was based on not reading the question properly. Didn't realise user had already tried that.