# Python pow() function returns wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, python-3.6

I am creating a basic RSA encryption program without using an RSA library that takes a secret message, converts each character in the string to its ASCII value, encrypts with a public key and concatenates the values, and then decrypts it using a private key and returns it to a string.

All with the principle of `cipher = pow(plain,e,n)` and `plain = pow(cipher,d,n)`. My issue is that when the numbers get very large as I need `d` and `n` to be 16 digits minimum, the `pow()` function seems to result in an error in calculation that yields an ASCII value that is out of range to convert to a character. I've been struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong for days now. Any help is appreciated. Code below:

```
from random import randrange, getrandbits

def is_prime(n, k=128):
    # Test if n is not even.
    # But care, 2 is prime !
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n <= 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    # find r and s
    s = 0
    r = n - 1
    while r & 1 == 0:
        s += 1
        r //= 2
    # do k tests
    for q in range(k):
        a = randrange(2, n - 1)
        x = pow(a, r, n)
        if x != 1 and x != n - 1:
            j = 1
            while j < s and x != n - 1:
                x = pow(x, 2, n)
                if x == 1:
                    return False
                j += 1
            if x != n - 1:
                return False

    return True

def generate_prime_candidate(length):
    # generate random bits
    p = getrandbits(length)
    #p = randrange(10**7,9*(10**7))
    # apply a mask to set MSB and LSB to 1
    p |= (1 << length - 1) | 1

    return p

def generate_prime_number(length=64):
    p = 4
    # keep generating while the primality test fail
    while not is_prime(p, 128):
        p = generate_prime_candidate(length)
    return p

def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def generate_keypair(p, q):
    n = p * q

    #Phi is the totient of n
    phi = (p-1) * (q-1)

    #Choose an integer e such that e and phi(n) are coprime
    e = randrange(1,65537)

    g = gcd(e, phi)
    while g != 1:
        e = randrange(1,65537)
        g = gcd(e, phi)

    d = multiplicative_inverse(e, phi)
    return ((e, n), (d, n))

def multiplicative_inverse(e, phi):
    d = 0
    k = 1
    while True:
        d = (1+(k*phi))/e
        if((round(d,5)%1) == 0):
            return int(d)
        else:
            k+=1

def encrypt(m,public):
    key, n = public
    encrypted = ''
    print("Your original message is: ", m)
    result = [(ord(m[i])) for i in range(0,len(m))]
    encryption = [pow(result[i],key,n) for i in range(0,len(result))]
    for i in range(0,len(encryption)):
        encrypted = encrypted + str(encryption[i])
    #encrypted = pow(int(encrypted),key,n)
    print("Your encrypted message is: ", encrypted)
    #return result,encrypted
    return encrypted, encryption

def decrypt(e,c,private):
    key, n = private
    print("Your encrypted message is: ", c)
    print(e)
    decryption = [pow(e[i],key,n) for i in range(0,len(e))]
    print(decryption)
    result = [chr(decryption[i])for i in range(0,len(decryption)) ]
    decrypted = ''.join(result)
    print("Your decrypted message is: ",decrypted)
    return result,decrypted

def fastpow(x,y,p):
    res = 1
    x = x%p

    while(y>0):
        if((y&1) == 1):
            res = (res*x)%p
        y = y>>1
        x = (x*x)%p
    return res



message = input("Enter your secret message: ")
p1 = generate_prime_number()
p2 = generate_prime_number()
public, private = generate_keypair(p1,p2)
print("Your public key is ", public)
print("Your private key is ", private)
encrypted,cipher = encrypt(message,public)
decrypt(cipher,encrypted,private)
```

Traceback:

```
 File "<ipython-input-281-bce7c44b930c>", line 1, in <module>
   runfile('C:/Users/Mervin/Downloads/group2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mervin/Downloads')

 File "C:\Users\Mervin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\util\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
   execfile(filename, namespace)

 File "C:\Users\Mervin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\util\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
   exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

 File "C:/Users/Mervin/Downloads/group2.py", line 125, in <module>
   decrypt(cipher,encrypted,private)

 File "C:/Users/Mervin/Downloads/group2.py", line 100, in decrypt
   result = [chr(decryption[i])for i in range(0,len(decryption)) ]

 File "C:/Users/Mervin/Downloads/group2.py", line 100, in <listcomp>
   result = [chr(decryption[i])for i in range(0,len(decryption)) ]

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23759098/1531971 (You should say what version of Python you are using, and maybe 2.5+ addresses many of your problems. You should also show some example output.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  The key word here is "minimal".

Comment: Your `multiplicative_inverse()` method is wrong. Take a look at [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Comment: When you say "seems to result in an error in calculation", are you actually getting an error? If so, please provide the full traceback. If not, please provide sample input and output

Comment: @DanielPryden: incorrect

Comment: Edited with version 3.6.4, the fastpow() function I wrote isn't being used currently, I'm familiar with pow(a,b,c) for modular exponentiation and that's what I'm using in my code currently.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: I don't see what I've done wrong with this function, is it due to my rounding?

Comment: I provided you with a link. Please read it.

Comment: When things seem to be wrong and there are two choices: 1. "The implementation that has been used by thousands of people for years is wrong" or "I don't understand" choose the second and really dig in to understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `multiplicative_inverse` is not correct. I'm not certain what you are doing in that method with the round method and floating point division, but even if you got that part correct it would be too slow anyway, requiring O(φ) steps. The usual method for computing [modular multiplicative inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) is an adaptation of the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures), which runs in O(log(φ)<sup>2</sup>) steps. Here is a straightforward mapping from the psuedocode in the Wikipedia article to python 3 code:

```
def multiplicative_inverse(a, n):
    t, newt = 0, 1
    r, newr = n, a
    while newr:
        quotient = r // newr
        t, newt = newt, t - quotient * newt
        r, newr = newr, r - quotient * newr
    if r > 1:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("{} is not invertible".format(a))
    if t < 0:
        t = t + n
    return t
```